# Error System.IO al instalar programa en otra pc

Tags: c#, mysql

como andan ? Me tira un error cuando quiero conectarme a la BD desde la aplicación que hice con windows forms, dice algo así:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o
>   ensamblado 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' ni una de sus dependencias. El
>   sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. Nombre de archivo:
>   'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'

Busqué y es supuestamente por el conector OBDC de  MySQl. Lo descargue y aun así me sigue tirando el error, alguno tiene una idea?

Comment: que tiene que ver el titulo de la pregunta? :)... esto te pasa en debug o una vez que corres el programa en otra pc?

Comment: No se porque se puso ese titulo jajaja! Se puede editar? Me pasa una vez que corro el programa en otra pc, desde la pc donde lo programe no pasa nada. Es más, tengo la BD en otra pc y le instale el programa al host y me tira tambien ese error

Comment: si.. el boton [edit] esta para justamente eso. cuando mandas tu programa a otra pc, tenes que mandar todos los paquetes necesarios para ejecutarlo. Eso incluye las dll de conexion a la base de datos, que ya tenes instalada en tu pc. A veces no alcanza con descargarlas, porque capaz no es exactamente la misma version

Comment: validaste que junto al .exe esta la dll de MySql.Data ?

Comment: Como hago para incluir las dll? Yo tengo por ejemplo en lareferencia de Mysql.data en las propiedades donde dice copia local esta en true.

Comment: pero el problema se presenta cuando ejecutas desde el VS, o cuando haces el deploy en la pc del usuario? porque el copy local en true solo aplica cuando ejecutas desde el VS, cuando llevas la app a otra pc debes validar que este esa dll, o si usas algun soft que crea el instalador que la incluya

Comment: Ahi pude solucionarlo, puse en la carpeta del .exe los .dll que faltaban! Gracias!